# Does the new Hyperledger fabric sdk support chaincode installation and instantiation?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

This is a statement from Hyperledger Fabric NodeJS SDK v2.2 documentation in the section "[Migrating client applications from v1.4 to v2.0](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/tutorial-migration.html)":

> Note that the SDK no longer aims to provide administrative and
> management capability. The command-line interface should be used for
> these operations.

Does this mean that the new SDK does not support actions like chaincode installation and instantiation. I understand that in v2.2 the chaincode lifecycle is different and the steps are package and install chaincode, approve and commit chaincode definition. Can any of these actions be performed using the SDK?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Hyperledger Fabric SDK GO](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go). It currently supports Fabric v2.2.

You can check our repo [Akachain Admin Tool](https://github.com/Akachain/akc-admin-go) as an example. It provides RESTful API for an administrator to interact with a Hyperledger Fabric network using Fabric Go SDK